# Strange issue with GPIO on STM32G070CBT6 - Register shows output value in ODR register, but the pin level doesn't toggle

Tags: stm32, gpio

I have a strange issue with a STM32G070CBT6.

My issue is that regardless of what my code and the registers show, the output on PB15 doesn't change.

I used CubeMX to create my project where only PB15, PB14, PB12 and PB2 is set to an output with no pull-up or pull-down, in push-pull mode. All the other GPIO were set to input with pull-down, except for the osc pins and the power pins. That way, I made sure that no other components where interfering and causing the issue.

For each of those pin, the same components are attached : A 120ohm resistor in parallel to a 100kohm resistor. The 100k resistor goes to ground while the 120 ohm resistor goes to a MOSFET (IRLML2402).

I can toggle the pins PB14,PB12 and PB2 no problem. But PB15 doesn't toggle regardless of what is done.

I use a Jlink trace with IAR, and in my GPIOB register, ODR and IDR is set t 0x00008000, and MODER 0x51000010, meaning that PB15 is indeed set as an output, and should switch the pin to HIGH.

This is the initialization created with cubeMX.

PB15 -> MOTOR1_2

PB14 -> MOTOR2_1

PB12 -> MOTOR1_1

PB2 -> MOTOR2_2

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, MOTOR2_2_Pin|MOTOR1_1_Pin|MOTOR2_1_Pin|MOTOR1_2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC13 PC6 PC7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA0 PA1 PA2 PA3 
                           PA4 PA5 PA6 PA7 
                           PA8 PA9 PA10 PA11 
                           PA12 PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3 
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7 
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11 
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB1 PB10 PB11 
                           PB13 PB3 PB4 PB5 
                           PB6 PB7 PB8 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11 
                          |GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5 
                          |GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : MOTOR2_2_Pin MOTOR1_1_Pin MOTOR2_1_Pin MOTOR1_2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MOTOR2_2_Pin|MOTOR1_1_Pin|MOTOR2_1_Pin|MOTOR1_2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD0 PD1 PD2 PD3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

And I toggle each of the four output in my main loop where I use breakpoint to check my physical output value. PB14,PB12 and PB2 toggle correctly. PB15 doesn't toggle at all regardless of what is in ODR and MODER.

```
 while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR2_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR2_1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR2_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR2_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   // HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,MOTOR1_2_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

As a last ditch effort, I lifted the pin PB15 so it's not connected to anything and toggle the pin. Still no success.

I tried this manipulation on multiple board and they all have the same issue. I am at loss here. I checked the documentation over and over again to see if I missed something about PB15 in the STM32G070CBT6 but  saw nothing.

Not sure where to look next.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any chance PB15 is used as alternate function for a  peripheral ?

Comment: What are the values of the other GPIOs registers just before you try to toggle its output ?

Comment: I want to use the PB15 eventually as a PWM, but for the moment it's strictly set as a GPIO. PUPDR is 0x08AAAAAA. OTYPER, PSPEEDR, LCKR, AFRL and AFRH set to 0x00000000. I created a blank MXCube projet with only PB15,PB14,PB12 and PB2 as GPIO, with no special function enabled.

Comment: Since MODER is 0x51000010, the msb bits are 01, meaning PB15 is in GPIO mode, not alternate function

Answer (score 0):

I still did not find the issue for this problem. Maybe extreme bad luck, but after trying a 4th board, the 4th board worked correctly. So maybe there was an issue with the production.

Anyhow, I am closing this question.